# unpacked size of my node module suddenly increased much bigger with no much change

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, filesize, npm-publish

I created this node package

When it was the version of 1.7.3, Its unpacked size was only 618KB

But after updating to the version of 2.0.0 with just a little file change, its size became 4.35 MB

The super weird thing is the fact that I rather reduced file size after the 1.7.3 version by removing a third-party module that I had imported and a few js and CSS files from this project but still, it's 4.13MB

1.I don't think the unpacked size is related to the actual size of the node module. is that right?

2. If I'm correct what exactly is unpacked size and is there a way to reduce the size?
3. If I'm wrong, what factors might have increased the size? and How could I reduce the unpacked size?

### Note

I started this project with `npx create-react-library` command.
created by https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library
Whenever I was trying to publish, what I did was just one command

```
npm publish
```

this command did all work for me to publish.

This was my first time to create a node package. So please understand me if it turns out to be a very silly mistake.

Comment: I am guessing the nupacked size is the amt of recources taken up on host machine once installed, once your package gets "unwrapped" by the end user.

Comment: Hi, can you add what else is being packed into the tarball using the `npm pack` command

Comment: @RishabhAnand  I don't really understand what I should do with `npm pack` command. do you mean that you want me to post the mylibrary.tgz file here ?

Comment: @NathanToulbert could you elaborate on that, please? I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: @Shawn the output of `npm pack` command. U are using `files` and `.npmignore`, just need to make sure whatever you're packing is truly what you're packing

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is packed into tgz or tar.gz, it is basically just the same thing as a zip file. They just use different algorithms for compression of data. They compress this data so that the download experience is more convenient. Smaller files mean quicker download times.

That said, The smaller size and larger sizes will be directly correlated. Imagine pushing the air out of a bag of potato chips. Although this will make any bag smaller, a full bag will still occupy the most space.

2. As we discussed earlier, the unpacked size is the size that your application will eventually be once it is installed on a machine. The same method used to zip it into a tgz file is used to reinflate it on the other end of the download, so that it can be used by node. The size that your package was just before you packed it should be the same size that it ends up being after it is unpacked. This is what 'unpacked size' is referring to.  The correlation isn't perfect. In other words, a project twice the size doesn't mean a power ball twice the size. Other factors are at play. The average size for a single file in your package has a lot to do with it as well. In the earlier analogy, imagine crushing all of the potato chips to crumbs before pushing the air out. You would still be packing the same amount of chips, but would need a lot less space.
3. This is where the answer gets a bit murky. It is hard to know for sure what is causing your file size to bloat without actually seeing the unpacked files for both versions. With that said, I'm sure that you could do a very small bit of investigation and figure it out on your own. It is just simple math. The file sizes of your individual files, when added together, should be just a little less than the unpacked size of your package. The conversion from unpacked size 2 tarball size is as I mentioned above.

**One thing that I will point out and highlight is that you need to check your dependencies for malicious software. If you don't trust it, as a rule, don't use it. If version 3 of a dependency is 3 times the size of version 2 with no reason, it is suspect.**

Just yesterday, I read that more than 3000 docker images on docker hub currently contain malware. Doctor hub is used by industry leaders everyday!

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. I did investigate the two version of my package to find out why its size grew massively, using npm pack command. As a result, I found out that I imported the third-party library that is very heavy into my project by mistake.